# MYSQL automatically insert csv files from folder using mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, csv, import, directory, mysqlimport

I would like to import around 3000 CSV files from a specified "folder" automatically at a designated time.
Everyday the CSV files will be updated to include new data.

I understand that I should use the command line tool "mysqlimport" and --replace option, (as sometimes old data will be altered)

Comment: looks like something you could do with cron (not a mysql tool). Are you running linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq(field1, field2, field3)
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

This is an optional solution, the only thing you'll need is an PHP\Perl\Python script to itreate over all of the files, and insert them one by one

PHP code:

```
<?php

    $basedir = "/path/to/dir"
    if ($handle = opendir($basedir)) {
      while(false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $basedir$entry
                    INTO TABLE tableName
                    FIELDS
                    TERMINATED BY ','
                    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    ESCAPED BY '\\'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES");
        if(DEBUG) { echo $query . "\n"; }
        if(!mysql_query($query)) {
          die('MySQL error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Could not open $basedir";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you be more specific @oleg. i got the same requirement as above, wondering around for a better and efficient solution.

the command u said above doesn't load all the files from a folder, we have to write individually.