# Hyperlink forces file download - how to save file on server?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to build a website which mainly shows data in charts. Data for charts should come from MySQL database. Currently I don't know **how to save a CSV file on my server** to feed my database later.

The problem is that the file is saved on another server and only offered by hyperlink which references to an PHP file (f.e. www.asdf.com/fore_csv_download.php).

**Is there a possibility to download the CSV file to my Server?**

Once the File is saved I should be able to load data into the database with this: [MYSQL automatically insert csv files from folder using mysqlimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269825/mysql-automatically-insert-csv-files-from-folder-using-mysqlimport)

Later I'm thinking of automate this process with `cron` jobs.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm currently reviewing your question and it's quiet unclear to me at the moment. Could you please elaborate more on your setup? I barely read there are two servers and you want to download a file from one server to the other and then read that file into a database.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php - You can try to use this function to get file from remote server and then save it on your disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need retrieve file in other server use CURL, eg:

```
<?ph
$source = 'http://www.asdf.com/fore_csv_download.php';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

file_put_contents('/var/www/data/file.csv', $data);
```

If need download for local, create a page like this (eg. download.php):

```
<?php
$file = FULL PATH CSV FILE from "Database" (only a example);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');

echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first example is what I was looking for. Works now!